# Advice needed for Querying DateTimeOffset data by end users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, datetime

We are building an Operational Data Store (ODS). The data is coming from our production databases which are located in the United States and Asia. The data in our production databases store date/time values as local time (no UTC or offsets). When we bring the data into our ODS, we're storing all date/time values as DateTimeOffset values.

When our users query the ODS data, we don't want them to have to think about including the appropriate offset value in their queries involving date/time values. We want them to be able to query the data as if it were simple local time values.

We're masking the offset values on date/time values by having users query views. The views return local time values and strip off the offset values. While this works, any indexes on the underlying datetimeoffset columns are not used because the act of converting the datetimeoffset to datetime in the views causes indexes to not be used.

So, I'm looking for advice on how others, who have dealt with this issue, have dealed with it. We need to be able to utilize indexes while, at the same time, not require users to think about time zones and daylight savings time when querying the data.

We're using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Store as UTC. Then everything is at par and you can always convert to local time zone when you need to (and the presentation side can handle that, as well as handle converting seek parameters *from* the client's time zone). One weakness you may not have noticed yet abut `DateTimeOffset`: it is not DST-aware.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks. I don't see how storing UTC solves my problem. When users query the ODS UTC data they would need to know how to convert the UTC values to local time to query the data correctly. If a user wants to see all rows where some value is, say, greater than 8/20/2013 5:00:00 AM, they are thinking in terms of local time, but the data is UTC. They would have to convert their query value to UTC first. Or, the UTC needs to be converted to local time, but then any index on the column won't get used.

Comment: Can't the application convert for them? *It* knows the difference between their time zone and UTC. Another idea is to use a calendar table, which is a solution I used in the past for an application developed long before DateTimeOffset even existed, and when time zone handling in C# was much less mature. You have a function that returns the offset based on TimeZone and Date, and add/subtract the number of minutes before passing that value to the actual query. The user doesn't have to think.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - There is no application. This is an ODS that users will be querying directly for ad-hoc queries, reporting, and other sorts of data analysis.

Comment: Ok, sorry that I don't have experience with an ODS. Can you create stored procedures for the users to call? Otherwise, how does a user indicate that 5:00 AM means 5:00 AM in their time zone? If two people query the same row, how do you distinguish when one of them is a user in California and the other one is in the UK?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The location of the user doesn't matter. Where the data came from does matter. It either came from United states (Ohio) or Malaysia. When users query our data, they will expect to query date/time fields based on the local time of the source of the data. For example, a user may want to see all rows where our product went through our Malaysian manufacturing line between 5:00 AM and 6 AM. When they enter these times in their query, they will assume Malaysian local time, not UTC time or offset time. Hope that's somewhat clear.

Comment: I still don't understand how you're going to know that the user is asking for Malaysian data or American data. If all you make them tell you is 5:00 AM, how are you going to know which "local" data to get?

Comment: And, again, you're not going to be able to use datetimeoffset to magically solve this, and particularly without some additional work, unless you don't care about DST shifts.

Comment: Hmm. I always thought that the ODS was a repository that wasn't for end users to query but was there to serve your marts

Answer (score 1):

We solved this in Oracle using function based indexes. Although, it's not quite as flexible, you can accomplish similar in SQL Server using computed columns.

If all of the information you need is in the table, and you meet all of the ownership requirements (outlined in the second article) then I would recommend making the date/time field a computed column on the table, and then add an index to the computed column.

Computed Columns:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Indexing Computed Columns:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292

Comment: So are you recommending a computed, indexed column for every possible timezone any user might be in?

Comment: Interesting. This might work. I'll have to study this.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Yes, that's correct. In our case, there were only 2 possibles. ET and GMT, so that was manageable.